# Defining Symfony2 services in a package which isn't a bundle

Tags: php, symfony

I'm building a bundle for a Symfony app which uses several different components which I've written. I'll call the bundle MyAppBundle.

The components which my bundle uses are not themselves dependent on Symfony, but I'd like to be able to define a set of Symfony services for each component, which will be defined within a services.yml file in each individual package - BUT I don't want these packages to be fully blown bundles.

Why? Because I don't want the packages to be dependent on the Symfony framework, I don't want to have to structure the packages as Symfony bundles, and I want to be able to register all required services for my app by registering the single MyAppBundle, while giving myself the flexibility to use the services from these components in an unrelated Symfony app if I wish. If I made these into full blown bundles then I'd have to load each bundle individually in my AppKernel, which I don't want.

This should be easy - as per the documentation I just need to build a container extension: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#importing-configuration-via-container-extensions

So I make a container extension for my component to load its service definitions:

```
namespace MyComponent;

class MyComponentExtension extends \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\Extension
{

    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
    }

}
```

I'm just not sure how I can load this extension from MyAppBundle? There seems to be very little information around on how to load an extension from another bundle. Maybe this isn't the recommended way of doing things but for the reasons described above I think my use case is justified.

My best attempt so far at loading the MyComponentExtension from MyAppBundle is:

```
namespace MyAppBundle;

class MyAppBundle extends Bundle
{

    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $extensions = array(
            new MyComponentExtension(),
            new MyOtherComponentExtension()
        );
        $aliases = array();
        foreach($extensions as $extension) {
            $container->registerExtension($extension);
            $aliases[] = $extension->getAlias();
        }
        $container->addCompilerPass(new MergeExtensionConfigurationPass($aliases));
    }

}
```

The "addCompilerPass" bit was gleaned from the little information I can find and I'm fairly sure it's wrong. When I do this I'm unable to access the services provided by MyComponentExtension. I'm pretty certain I just need to make sure the definitions are compiled into the container properly but am unsure how to do this!

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of coupling: Hard Coupling and Soft Coupling.
Then you have Decoupling.

**Decoupling**

When you decouple a component from a bundle, you either have each part dependent on a common interface (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle).

Or you can have a unidirectional dependency.  In this instance the bundle will become dependent on the component.  An example of the is the Symfony Framework Bundle being dependent on the Symfony components.

For the first example you would use configuration to define which classes to use.
Then included for the second you would define the services within the bundle for the classes of the component.  Again, this is what the Symfony Framework Bundle does.

**Soft Coupling**

This is when a library references another (or an abstraction of another), but does not require it (unless you attempt to use it, after which it indirectly becomes a hard dependency).  Such as additional features that are omitted if the resources to provide it are absent.

An example of this is placing your dependency injection within the component, providing support for Symfony, but not requiring it.

For an example take a look at `Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\DependencyInjection\AbstractDoctrineExtension`.

The common strategy is to create an abstract extension, then override it in the bundle.
The bundle can then override parts of the component if further integration is required (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

**Either way**

The ideal situation is a component which can be used by itself (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), and only using Symfony to bootstrap them as services.

Decoupled

```
Bundle => depends on => Component
Component depends on nothing
```

Soft Dependency

```
Bundle => depends on => Component  
Component -> supports -> Symfony
```

What you should never do though is create a bidirectional dependency.  That is each part statically depending on each other.

EDIT in response to how:

You can, although as to why you need to will remain a mystery to me.

```
class MyAppBundle extends Bundle
{
    /**
     * Override extension getter.
     */
    public function getContainerExtension()
    {
        if(null === $this->extension) {
            $this->extension = new My\Component\Extension();
        }

        return $this->extension;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer. Indeed I want the MyComponentExtension to have only a soft dependency on Symfony, but your answer doesn't tell me how I can correctly register my ComponentExtension from MyAppBundle!

Comment: In the example you've given of the AbstractDoctrineExtension, you still have to have a DoctrineBundle which has to be individually loaded from the AppKernel class - this is the situation I want to avoid as the MyAppBundle should load the MyComponentExtension itself.

Comment: Yes, but `Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DependencyInjection\DoctrineExtension` extends `AbstractDoctrineExtension` in bridge.

Comment: I understand that, but the DoctrineExtension is part of the DoctrineBundle and can only be loaded by registering the DoctrineBundle. My question was - can I register an extension with my app WITHOUT that extension being part of a bundle?

Comment: Updated to show how that is done.  My prior answer was an attempt to return you to the path of the faithful :P

Comment: Your example doesn't do what I'm trying to achieve - it only shows me how I can override the default extension for a bundle. This isn't what I'm trying to do. My situation is that I have X number of extensions. MyAppBundle is dependent on all these extensions and I therefore want ALL of these extensions to be registered when I load MyAppBundle. I want to register MyAppBundle by adding just 1 bundle in my AppKernel, not 5 or 6 which the MyAppBundle is dependent on.

Comment: I want to do this "the right way" but to do what you're suggesting I'd have to make a bundle from each of my extensions. I'd then have to load ALL of the bundles in my AppKernel, when really I just want to load the MyAppBundle, this way I know that whenever I load this one bundle I have all of its dependent services registered in my app.

Comment: How is that different to having a single extension which configures all of your components?  The abstract `Extension` class is only there to help integrate the services with the container.  There is nothing stopping you from passing the `Loader` and the `ContainerBuilder` to instances of an interface "you" created to dynamically enhance the work of that one extension.

Comment: I think that's what I'm going to have to do - create some other interface that the MyBundleExtension can use to load in services from my other components - I just thought that Symfony might provide an "official" way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You might be making this harder than it needs to be.  Your MyAppExtension can easily load services.yml from your component library.  No need for a component extension.

```
class MyAppBundleExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, 
            new FileLocator('path_to_component_library'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
    }
```

Getting the path to your component library is the only minor challenge but even hardcoding it won't be bad.

Having said that, you really should consider making a bridge bundle to your library.  All it really needs is a Bundle class, Extension class and the services.yml file.  Your library itself can stay exactly the way it is.

Bridges are what the Symfony 2 frameworks use to access libraries such as Twig and Doctrine.  Pretty sure they will work for your library as well.  Take a look at: vendor/symfony/monolog-bundle for an example.

Comment: This is somewhat similar to the approach I chose in the end. By using a static loader method in my component I've avoided hardcoding the path though. The reason for not making a bridge bundle is I only want to have to load one bundle in my AppKernel and not have to load other dependent bundles separately.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution I chose in the end. I created a loader class within MyComponent with a static buildContainer method:

```
<?php

namespace MyComponent;

use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader;

class MyComponentLoader
{

    /**
     * Loads component services into a container.
     *
     * @param ContainerBuilder $container
     */
    public static function buildContainer(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
    }

}
```

Then I load the services into my container from MyAppExtension within MyAppBundle:

```
<?php

namespace MyAppBundle\DependencyInjection;

use MyComponent\MyComponentLoader;
use MyOtherComponent\MyOtherComponentLoader;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader;

class SmartCloneExtension extends Extension
{

    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        MyComponentLoader::buildContainer($container);
        MyOtherComponentLoader::buildContainer($container);
    }

}
```

Comment: Okay but now you just violated your own requirement that your components not be dependent on Symfony 2.  Just seems a bit strange.

Comment: It is only a soft dependency though - the MyComponentLoader class has a buildContainer method which is dependent on the Symfony2 container, but the rest of the component can work standalone. I could have made a "bridge" package but for my purposes here this seemed like overkill.

Comment: Sure but why have any dependency at all when it's not needed?  It's perfectly fine but I did want to make sure that it was clear that you don't need any dependency at all to make it work.  And if you were going to have a dependency then adding a single bundle class which would make it a full fledged bundle does not seem like it's overkill.  But again, as long as it works for you.

Comment: I agree for something like an open source project a bridge package would definitely be preferable, but this is just internal to my organisation. The main thing I wanted to avoid is having to load multiple bundles in the AppKernel to get all the dependencies of my main bundle registered in the app, which is what I've achieved here.